# Dynamic Decorators in Python

Tags: python

```
from functools import wraps

WRAPTYPE = "DOES NOT WORK"

class Test():
    def __init__(self,wrapType):
        globals()["WRAPTYPE"] = wrapType
    
    def with_provider(wrapType):
        def decorator(func):
            @wraps(func)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                print("Argument passed to with_provider:", wrapType)
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            return wrapper
        return decorator

    # Example usage
    @with_provider(WRAPTYPE)
    def example_function(self):
        print("Inside example_function")

#%%
t = Test("WORKS")
t.example_function()
```

I want to be able to pass wrapType argument to the decorator at class initialization,, so that it prints "Argument passed to with_provider: WORKS" Is this possible?
It doesn't need to be done with `globals()`, if it can be done with `self.wrapType=wrapType` where  that self makes it way to the `with_provider` it would be great.

I tried the class above and it does not work, since at class initialization  the argument passed to the decorator seems to be immutable.
Need if possible for the decorator to be within the class for code cleaness

Comment: It doesn't work because `with_provider` is called while the class is being *defined*, not when you invoke `example_function`. At that point, `WRAPTYPE` is still equal to `DOES NOT WORK`, and that's the value that gets baked into `wrapper` (via the non-local variable `wrapType`).

Comment: damn using global variables, outside the class, to make a class behave in a way is so sad, thank you

Comment: There are two things you *might* want, each accomplished slightly differently. Do you want 1) For different instances of `Test` to have a fixed wrap-type, or 2) Do you want every instance to use whatever the current global value of `WRAPTYPE` is when its `example_function` method is called?

Comment: (Basically, it boils down to what should happen if you define `t1 = Test("FOO")` and `t2 = Test("BAR")`. There's only one global variable, so there's going to be some conflict, to say the least.)

Comment: Yeah i wanted to avoid usage of global variables, if it's possible. But if it's the only way, then that's that.

Comment: No, I'm asking what you want, so that you can avoid the global in *either* case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a `self` first argument.

```py
from functools import wraps

class Test():
    def __init__(self,wrapType):
        self.wrapType = wrapType
    
    def with_provider(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print("wrapType property of class instance:", self.wrapType)
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    # Example usage
    @with_provider
    def example_function(self):
        print("Inside example_function")

#%%
t = Test("WORKS")
t.example_function()
```

Comment: omg i didn't know it was this simple, thank you

Comment: Out of curiousity, how did this even work, because `self` is never provided to `with_provider` ?

Comment: @MagdaliniKlio Because now the function defined in `with_provider`, i.e. `wrapper` is the function being used that wraps `example_function`. it is just like any other function you define with `self` and put in a class, it gets provided with the *method is called*

Comment: Note that the original `with_provider` would work with *any* function, while this one would be expected to only apply to functions that take at least one argument. (Loosely speaking, it's been specialized to work only on methods.)

Comment: And even more specifically, it's been specialized to work with methods of classes that have a `wrapType` attribute (or functions that take an instance of such a class as the first argument).

Comment: thank you guys for the feedback, this answer solves this question, appreciate it. I was looking to be able to dynamically change the behavior of the wrapper based on a attribute in `self` and this does it perfectly.

Comment: @MagdaliniKlio Glad to help. If the answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted to help other people facing a similar problem.